# Is it true the eigenvalues for a shifted matrix (by itself raised to a power) equals sum of eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

It seems, although I cannot prove, that if we have a matrix $A$ with the eigenvalue $a$ that the eigenvalues $\lambda$ of 
$$(A+A^n)x = \lambda x \implies \lambda = a+a^n$$

*The last term follows by $Ax=\lambda x \implies A^nx=\lambda^nx$*.

This however, seems not to be true for $(A+B)x=\lambda x$ iff $B\not=A$.

- Is there any theorem to prove this? If not, what's an example where this is not true?

Added own thoughts:

Is the above perhaps the results of the fact that $A^n$ has the same eigenvectors as $A$?  Whereas $A$ and $B$ does not need to have the same eigenvectors.

Comment: If $A$ is a matrix with eigenvalue $\lambda$ then for any polynomial $f(T)$ the matrix $f(A)$ will have eigenvalue $f(\lambda)$. Your counterexample is useless because you're adding a random different matrix $B$ to $A$ and trying to keep the same eigenvalue.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I wasn't trying to provide a counter example, just making observations that might show to become clearer for me once I learned why the first case behaves as it does. However, I'm still not quite convinced.

Comment: Your statement would be true for any pair of simultaneously diagonalizable matrices.

Comment: Ah, you are asking a harder question than I thought. Theorem 2.1 of http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/tracenorm2.pdf is related to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last thought is indeed accurate.  We would need to use something like "$A$ and $A^n$ have the same eigenvectors" before concluding that
$(A + A^n)x = \lambda x$ implies that $x$ is an eigenvector of both $A$ and $A^n$.

In fact, $A$ and $A^n$ might not have all the same eigenvectors ($A^n$ might have some extras), so we're in even more trouble than you might have thought.

The usual way of bypassing this mess is to use the fact that any matrix $A$ can be upper-triangularized, either using [Schur factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition) or [Jordan canonical form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form).  Barring that, you could trace through an argument like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492070/how-to-prove-eigenvalues-of-polynomial-of-matrix-a-polynomial-of-eigenvalue).

Another typical (though perhaps sophisticated) argument that may work here is to use the fact that the set of the diagonalizable matrices is dense in $\Bbb C^{n \times n}$ and the continuous dependence of eigenvalues on matrix entries.