# Polynomial, set of eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A \in \text{M}_{n \times n}(\mathbb{C})$. How do I see that if $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, then for any polynomial $P(\cdot)$, I have that $P(\lambda_1), \dots, P(\lambda_n)$ are the eigenvalues for $P(A)$?

Comment: let $v$ be an eigenvector to eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then, $P(A)v = \dotsb = P(\lambda)v$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492070/how-to-prove-eigenvalues-of-polynomial-of-matrix-a-polynomial-of-eigenvalue?rq=1