# Finding $(B^2+I)^{-1}$ using eigenvalues and size.

Tags: linear-algebra

A $3\times 3$ matrix $B$ is known to have eigenvalues $0, 1$ and $2$. This information is
enough to find three of these (give the answers where possible):

1. The rank of $B$
2. The determinant of $BT B$
3. The eigenvalues of $BT B$
4. The eigenvalues of $(B^2 + I)^{−1}$

Comment: What is the $T$ in $BTB$? Should that be $B^TB$?

Answer (score 2):

We have that $A$ has eigenvalue $\lambda\iff A^{-1}$ has eigenvalue $\lambda^{-1}$.

To see this, note that:
\begin{align*}
Av & = \lambda v \\
A^{-1}Av & = \lambda A^{-1}v \\
v & = \lambda A^{-1}v \\
A^{-1}v & = \frac{1}{\lambda}v
\end{align*}
Here, we're assuming $A$ is invertible. This will be fine, as while $B$ isn't invertible, $B^2+I$ is.

Now, we have that $B^2+I$ has eigenvalues $0^2+1,1^2+1$, and $2^2+1$, or $1,2,5$.
It follows that $(B^2+I)^{-1}$ has eigenvalues $1,\frac{1}{2}$, and $\frac{1}{5}$.

Comment: Thank you! I wasnt sure if i could add the eigenvalues like that. This was invaluable for me thank you again!

Comment: @Controlsystemsengineer See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492070/how-to-prove-eigenvalues-of-polynomial-of-matrix-a-polynomial-of-eigenvalue), for example, for eigenvalues of a polynomial of a matrix.