# Eigenvectors and Orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

"Knowing that a matrix $B\in \Bbb{R^{3\times 3}}$ has eigenvalues $0$, $1$ e $2$. This information is enough to calculate three of the next items:

$(i)$ Rank of $B$;

$(ii)$ Determinant of $B^T B$;

$(iii)$ Eigenvalues of $B^T B$;

$(iv)$ Eigenvalues of $(B+I)^{-1}$.

What is the item that needs additional informations to be calculated? Calculate the other three."

The $(i)$ and $(iv)$ I know  how to calculate but I don't know about the others
.Someone posted [Finding $(B^2+I)^{-1}$ using eigenvalues and size.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2059736/finding-b2i-1-using-eigenvalues-and-size) that is almost equal, however the answer is not complete.

Comment: **Hint:** You can also find (ii).

Comment: For (iv), the eigenvalues of $B+I$ are $1,2,3$, so...

Comment: @Berci When I wrote that https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2059736/finding-b2i-1-using-eigenvalues-and-size is not complete I meant that only $(iv)$ is commented. Can you show me how to get $(ii)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** for (ii), we have $\det(AB)=\det A\cdot \det B$ for any square matrices, apply it with $A=B^T$ and observe $\det B=0$.

(By the way, $\det(B^T) =\det B$, so $\det(B^TB) =(\det B)^2$ also holds for any square matrix $B$.)