# Finding eigenvalues of transition matrix of a given Markov process (solution verification)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification, markov-chains

Consider sampling the uniform measure $\mathbb{Z}_L$ by the Markov chain $X^{(k)}$ with
$$P_i[X^{(i)}=(i+1)\mod L]=1$$
with initial condition $X^{(0)}=L-1$. Here $P_i$ means conditioning on $X_0=i$.
$$P_i[X^{(k)}=j]=\begin{cases}1, &\text{if }j=(i+k)\mod L\\0, &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
First, I compute the transition matrix. The state space is $\{0,1,\ldots,L-1\}$, and the Markov process permutes one element to the right each time, i.e.
$$[0,1,2,\ldots,L-1]\rightarrow[1,2,\ldots,L-1,0]\rightarrow[2,3,\ldots,L-1,0,1]\rightarrow\ldots$$
so
$$T=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0&\ldots&0&0\\0&0&1&0&\ldots&0&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\cdots&\vdots&\vdots\\0&0&0&0&\ldots&0&1\\1&0&0&0&\ldots&0&0\end{pmatrix}_{L\times L}$$
I am interested in finding the eigenvalues of $T$, $T^k$ for any $k$, and $F=\frac{1}{L}\sum_{k=1}^{L}T^k$.

For $T$, the eigenvalues are solution of $\lambda^L-1=0$, which are $L$-roots of unity $\lambda=e^{2\pi i\ell/L}$, where $\ell=0,1,\ldots, L-1$.

For $T^k$, the eigenvalues are the same as the first case, since the effect is just permuting the columns of $T$ cyclically, so the determinant of characteristic polynomial remains unchanged.

For $F$, first consider $J=\sum_{k=1}^{L}T^k$. Each column of $J$ consists of sum of all standard unit vectors $e_i$ and all the entries are $1$, so $J$ is $L\times L$ matrix whose entries are all $1$. So the rank of $J$ is just $1$, with eigenvalue $\lambda=0$ with multiplicity $L-1$ and $\lambda=L$, which is the result of $\pi T=\pi$, where $\pi$ is the stationary distribution, and we are viewing it as an eigenvector. Hence, the eigenvalues of $F=J/L$ is just either $0$ (with multiplicity $L-1$) or $1$.

I'd like to know whether my solutions are correct. If there are any flaws, can anyone point that out? Thank you.

**Edit:**

The second part of my original solution is wrong. Use the fact that if $\lambda_{\ell}$ are eigenvalues of $T$, then $\lambda_{\ell}^k$ are eigenvalues of $T^k$, we have the result.

Comment: For $T^k$ you are wrong. Consider $T^L$, for example. For the other two, I think you are right.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Can you expand your argument? Thanks.

Comment: The permutation of the columns of $T$ cyclically, does change the characteristic polynomial. I don't see why that does not change the characteristic polynomial. For example, take the $2 \times 2$ matrix involved, and square it.

Comment: My argument would go along the lines of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492070/how-to-prove-eigenvalues-of-polynomial-of-matrix-a-polynomial-of-eigenvalue) result. From the result, we can get the eigenvalues of any $T^k$, from the eigenvalues of $T$.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Yes, you are right. I checked the $4\times 4$ case. The result you mentioned is pretty useful. Thanks so much.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: So the eigenvalues of $T^k$ are just $e^{2\pi\ell k/L}$ for any $k$, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If $p$ is a polynomial, then the eigenvalues of $p(T)$ are $p(\lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.